# Ghostscript requires -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY when compiling pstricks-figures

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pstricks, ghostscript

I tried compiling pstricks-based figures using either `pdflatex --shell-escape` or `xelatex`, but both fail with

```
%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY

Error: /undefined in .setstrokeconstantalpha
Operand stack:
   1.0
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1974   1   3   %oparray_pop   1973   1   3   %oparray_pop   1961   1   3   %oparray_pop   1817   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:730/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:197/200(L)--   --dict:103/300(L)--   --dict:40/200(L)--   --dict:143/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 346494
GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
system returned with code 256
```

returned by `ghostscript`. Currently the only approach working is by chaining `latex`, `dvips -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` and `ps2pdf`, something which makes it more difficult to work with. Is there a way to include `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` directly when compiling the code with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`, or to somehow circumvent the issue?

As an example the following code triggers the issue for me, with `main.tex` as the main file, and `mwe.tex` as the ps-based figure:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
    \input{mwe.tex}
\end{document}
```

`mwe.tex`:

```
\begin{pspicture}(18,6)
    \psset[optexp]{fiber=none, usefiberstyle}
    %\newpsstyle{Fiber}{linecolor=orange, linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
    \newpsstyle{Fiber}{linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
    \pnodes(1.5, 4){LaserIn}(2, 4){LaserOut}
    \pnodes(1.5, 2){SESAMIn}(2, 2){SESAMOut}
    \pnodes(4, 4){InputIsolatorIn}(5, 4){InputIsolatorOut}
    \pnodes(6.5, 2){PolarizerIn}(7.5, 2){PolarizerOut}
    \pnodes(9, 4){TSFIn}(11, 4){TSFOut}
    \pnodes(14, 3){LoopIn}(14, 2){LoopOut}
    \pnodes(10, 1){OutputIsolatorIn}(12,1){OutputIsolatorOut}
    \pnodes(16, 1){LaserOutLow}
    \optdiode[compname=PumpDiode, position=start](LaserIn)(LaserOut){\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Laser\\diode\end{tabular}}
    \optisolator[compname=InputIsolator](InputIsolatorIn)(InputIsolatorOut){Pump Isolator}
    \optfiber[compname=ActiveFiber, position=start, linecolor=red](TSFIn)(TSFOut){Active fiber}
    
    \nput{75}{LaserOutLow}{Laser output}
    
    \drawfiber{InputIsolator}{ActiveFiber}
    \drawfiber{PumpDiode}{InputIsolator}
    \drawfiber{ActiveFiber}(LaserOutLow)
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: pdflatex doesn't call ghostscript directly, so it depends on what you are doing there. Without code it is difficult to say, similar for xelatex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `xetex`/`xelatex`, the backend driver `xdvipdfmx` calls Ghostscript to make automatic PS to PDF conversions. The Ghostscript command line that `xdvipdfmx` executes is configured in the file `dvipdfmx.cfg` whose default location is `$TEXMFDIST/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg`.

An up-to-date TeX installation, such as TeXLive-2021, should already have the GS call configured with `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY`. For your particular example, the setting `-dNOSAFER` is also needed, as some PSTricks header files need to be read in.

With TeXLive-2021 you will call `xelatex` as

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" main
```

If you have an older TeX installation you may want to put modified versions of `dvipdfmx.cfg` and `dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg` in the directory `$TEXMFLOCAL/dvipdfmx/`
where the GS command line is configured as

`dvipdfmx.cfg`:

```
D  "rungs -q -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit"
```

and `dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg`:

```
D  "rungs -q -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dNOSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit"
```

The `$TEXMFLOCAL` directory can be found with

```
kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
```

at the command prompt.

---

For `pdflatex`, configure `auto-pst-pdf` as

```
\usepackage[pspdf={-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY}]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

To get rid of the `Non-PDF special ignored!` warning while assembling the main PDF, disable the `\special` command by adding

```
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdf\def\special#1{}\fi
```

directly after `\documentclass...`

Comment: That works, thanks! How would I use that command line for pdflatex, though? That would make it even more convenient, after everything else in my documents is compiled using pdflatex.

Comment: Seems possible by adding an option to auto-pst-pdf (see edit).

Comment: I have the -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dSAFER options in /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg, which is the file returned by kpsewhich -progname=dvipdfmx -format=othertext dvipdfmx.cfg and yet ps2pdf fails with 

%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY

Error: /undefined in .setstrokeconstantalpha

ps2pdf  -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -dNOSAFER works though. What could explain that the dvipdfmx.cfg file is ignored ?