# pspicture not working in TexLive 2022 (Ubuntu 22.04), it works in TexLive 2019

Tags: texlive, pstricks, incompatibility

For the following code, I don't have the same result in Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 with TexLive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\pssize}\setlength{\pssize}{1cm}
\newcommand{\logotextformat}{\sffamily \bfseries \large}

\newcommand{\logoimg}[2]{
    \begin{pspicture}(#1,-#2)
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.88 0.15 0.11}
        \psset{
            unit=0.7pt,
            linestyle=none,
            fillstyle=solid,
            fillcolor=curcolor
        }
        \pscustom{
            \newpath
            \moveto(74, 18)
            \lineto(56, 18)
            \lineto(56, 12)
            \lineto(68, 12)
            \lineto(68, 12)
            \curveto(67, 7)(63, 5)(57, 5)
            \curveto(50, 5)(45, 10)(45, 17)
            \curveto(45, 24)(50, 30)(57, 30)
            \curveto(63, 30)(67, 27)(69, 23)
            \lineto(74, 25)
            \curveto(71, 32)(65, 35)(57, 35)
            \curveto(47, 35)(39, 27)(39, 17)
            \curveto(39, 7)(47, 0)(57, 0)
            \curveto(62, 0)(66, 2)(69, 5)
            \lineto(69, 1)
            \lineto(74, 1)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \lineto(74, 17)
            \closepath
        }
        \pscustom{
            \newpath
            \moveto(27, 61)
            \lineto(5, 61)
            \lineto(5, 75)
            \lineto(0, 75)
            \lineto(0, 42)
            \lineto(5, 42)
            \lineto(5, 56)
            \lineto(27, 56)
            \lineto(27, 42)
            \lineto(33, 42)
            \lineto(33, 75)
            \lineto(27, 75)
            \closepath
        }
    \end{pspicture}
}

\newcommand{\placelogo}[2]{% \logo{<left>}{<top>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, align=center,]
        \node(logo) at ([xshift=#1, yshift=-#2] current page.north west)
        [anchor=north west] {\logoimg{#1}{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
    \placelogo{2cm}{3cm}
\end{document}
```

### Build

I build the project with

```
latexmk -xelatex test.tex
```

### TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)

The logo is visible as expected.

[image]

### TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)

Logo not displayed.

[image]

Comment: ghostscript added security options. Compile with `xelatex-unsafe` (or compile with lualatex), see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/642533/2388

Comment: Or if `xelatex-unsafe` is not available you can use `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" yourfile.tex` as mentioned in the question that Ulrike linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider replacing the pstricks code by tikz commands, since you are using tikz anyway. I have transcribed the logo, see below, using [How do I achieve this in simple TikZ commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409151/110998). The following output is generated by a current TeX distribution using `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or whatever, without the need for additional command-line arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\logoimg}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7pt,y=0.7pt]%\begin{pspicture}(#1,-#2)
        \definecolor{curcolor}{rgb}{0.88,0.15,0.11} %\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.88 0.15 0.11}
        %\psset{
        %    unit=0.7pt,
        %    linestyle=none,
        %    fillstyle=solid,
        %    fillcolor=curcolor
        %  }
        \fill[curcolor] %\pscustom{\newpath
            (74,18)%\moveto(74, 18)
            -- (56,18)%\lineto(56, 18)
            -- (56,12)%\lineto(56, 12)
            -- (68,12)%\lineto(68, 12)
            %-- (68,12)%\lineto(68, 12) again???
            .. controls (67,7) and (63,5) .. (57,5)%\curveto(67, 7)(63, 5)(57, 5)
            .. controls (50,5) and (45,10) .. (45,17)%\curveto(50, 5)(45, 10)(45, 17)
            .. controls (45,24) and (50,30) .. (57,30)%\curveto(45, 24)(50, 30)(57, 30)
            .. controls (63,30) and (67,27) .. (69,23)%\curveto(63, 30)(67, 27)(69, 23)
            -- (74,25)% \lineto(74, 25)
            .. controls (71,32) and (65,35) .. (57,35)%\curveto(71, 32)(65, 35)(57, 35)
            .. controls (47,35) and (39,27) .. (39, 17)%\curveto(47, 35)(39, 27)(39, 17)
            .. controls (39,7) and (47,0) .. (57,0)%\curveto(39, 7)(47, 0)(57, 0)
            .. controls (62,0) and (66,2) .. (69,5)%\curveto(62, 0)(66, 2)(69, 5)
            -- (69,1)%\lineto(69, 1)
            -- (74,1)%\lineto(74, 1)
            -- (74,17)%\lineto(74, 17)
            %-- (74,17)%\lineto(74, 17) again???
            %-- (74,17)%\lineto(74, 17) and again???
            -- cycle%\closepath
        ;%}
        \fill[curcolor]%\pscustom{\newpath
            (27,61)%\moveto(27, 61)
            -- (5,61)%\lineto(5, 61)
            -- (5,75)%\lineto(5, 75)
            -- (0,75)%\lineto(0, 75)
            -- (0,42)%\lineto(0, 42)
            -- (5,42)%\lineto(5, 42)
            -- (5,56)%\lineto(5, 56)
            -- (27,56)%\lineto(27, 56)
            -- (27,42)%\lineto(27, 42)
            -- (33,42)%\lineto(33, 42)
            -- (33,75)%\lineto(33, 75)
            -- (27,75)%\lineto(27, 75)
            -- cycle%\closepath
        ;%}
    \end{tikzpicture}%\end{pspicture}
  }

\newcommand{\placelogo}[2]{% \logo{<left>}{<top>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, align=center,]
        \node(logo) at ([xshift=#1, yshift=-#2] current page.north west)
        [anchor=south west] {\logoimg{#1}{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \placelogo{2cm}{3.25cm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with a simple typesetting of the two characters. You can use another fonr to get similar characters to your (complecated) drawing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{logocolor}{rgb}{0.88,0.15,0.11}

\newcommand\logotextformat{\fontsize{1cm}{1.1cm}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}

\newcommand\logoimg{%
    \makebox(0,0){\logotextformat\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\tabcolsep0pt\tabular{ll}
        \textcolor{logocolor}{H}\\[-12pt] &\textcolor{logocolor}{G}\endtabular}}
    
\newcommand\placelogo[2]{% \logo{<left>}{<top>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, align=center,]
        \node(logo) at ([xshift=#1, yshift=-#2] current page.north west)
        [anchor=north west] {\logoimg};
    \end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
    \placelogo{2.5cm}{2.5cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]